# Session values not loading on next page

Tags: php, session

I am binding the session values in one page -

```
$_SESSION['order'] = $order;
$_SESSION['total'] = $gtot;
```

and fetching on next page-

```
$order = $_SESSION['order'];
$gtot = $_SESSION['total'];
```

...but in next next page I am getting blank session.

I have started session with  `session_start();`

When I check session values in previous page with `print_r($_SESSION['order']);` I get the proper values.

Comment: Can you post more of your code?  Also, where are you calling session_start()?  It should be at the top, at least before any output.

Comment: Are you calling `session_start` on both pages? And are the session IDs on both requests identical (just echo [`session_id`](http://php.net/session_id)?

Answer (score 1):

You first start SESSION on your both page,

```
session_start();
```

and try. give feedback on comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use session_start(); in the beginning of any code using session variables in your PHP web pages so that it works fine.

check this PHP manual url:-

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

I hope this helps you..

Answer (score 0):

First you have to start SESSION your both page like 'searc page' and 'search result page'

In search page just store your input value like:

```
<input type="text" name="name"/>
<input type="submit" value=">>"/>
```

In Search page store your NAME value in SESSION like:

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $fname;
```

Now, ECHO $_SESSION variable in search result page like:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $fname ?>"/>
```

**Hope it work simply.. if its works please tick sloved.**